# Making a column based on the order of another column

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a table called cars with a bunch of columns.

I want to make a column called "Make_ID" that will increment based on the alphabetical order or a column "Make".

My goal is to give each Make String a unique integer such as that wherever I have a record with a Make of "Ford", that Make_ID will always be, for example, the number 3 or if I have a Make of "Mazda" that Make_ID number will be 15 for ever record that has a Make of Mazda.

Is there a way to this?

Comment: You want a separate table called `makes` with an auto-incremented primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the data and just want this in a result set, then use `dense_rank()`:

```
select c.*, dense_rank() over (order by make) as make_id
from cars c
```

Comment: This was a real life saver Thanks